# How to assert Download has been started or completed in Nightwatch (w/ Saucelabs)

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js, assertion, saucelabs

I have an app that creates a .csv on-the-fly when clicking a button. I need to assert that the download has at least started.
I found some examples of a download sitting on the server and being able to assert a 200 response from the server.  How would I do this in my case, where nothing is sitting on the server?  I can see in saucelabs that it has been downloaded in the screen capture.

Comment: I'll leave this as unsolved, but this was my pseudo solution...  I created a cookie when the  file-saver.saveAs() method starts, then test for the cookie later in nightwatch using its .getCookies() command, then delete from the test using .deleteCookie().  Not the best, but at least it tells me it's probably working...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module. 
npm install request

Very easy and quick doing of actions like yours.